# why my text isnt displayed corona sdk

Tags: lua, coronasdk

hi i spent 2 days trying to figure out the problem but i couldnt so i ask you 
myText variable doesnt display it is suppose to say score i know that i am not updating score but tht doesnt matter yet 
heres the code:

```
  display.setStatusBar( display.HiddenStatusBar )
-- Start Physics
local physics = require("physics")
physics.start()
-- Set Variables
_W = display.contentWidth; -- Get the width of the screen
_H = display.contentHeight; -- Get the height of the screen
motionx = 0; -- Variable used to move character along x axis
motiony = 0; -- Variable used to move character along y axis
speed = 2; -- Set Walking Speed
jump = 3;-- set jumping speed
score=0;
local myText = display.newText(score,_W-20,_H-20, native.systemFont, 30 )
-- Add Sky to the background
local sky = display.newImage("background_sky.png")
sky.x = _W/2; sky.y = 160;
-- add platform1 to game
local platform1 = display.newImage( "grass.png")
platform1.width=100;platform1.height=20;platform1.x=150;platform1.y=_H/2;
physics.addBody(platform1,"static",{ friction=0.5, bounce=0.3 })
-- add platform2 to game
local platform2 = display.newImage( "grass.png")
platform2.width=100;platform2.height=20;platform2.x=350;platform2.y=_H/2-70;
physics.addBody(platform2,"static",{ friction=0.5, bounce=0.3 })

-- Add Grass floor to game
local grass_bottom = display.newImage( "grass_bottom.png")
grass_bottom.x = _W/2; grass_bottom.y = _H-35;
--grass_bottom:setReferencePoint(display.BottomLeftReferencePoint)
physics.addBody( grass_bottom, "static", { friction=0.5, bounce=0.3 } )

-- Add Grass to the background
local grass_top = display.newImage( "grass_top.png")
grass_top.x = _W/2; grass_top.y = _H-95;

-- Add Guy
local guy = display.newImage( "guy.png" )
physics.addBody( guy, "dynamic", { friction=0.5, bounce=0 } )
guy.x = 2; guy.y = 150;

-- Add left joystick button
local left = display.newImage ("btn_arrow.png")
left.x = 45; left.y = 280;
left.rotation = 180;

-- Add right joystick button
local right = display.newImage ("btn_arrow.png")
right.x = 120; right.y = 282;
-- add up joystick button
local up = display.newImage ("btn_arrow.png")
up.x = 195;up.y=280;
up.rotation=-90;

-- Stop character movement when no arrow is pushed
local function stop (event)
    if event.phase =="ended" then
        motionx = 0;
        motiony = 0;
    end
end
Runtime:addEventListener("touch", stop )

-- Move character
local function moveguy (event)
    if guy.x < _W - 2 then
     if guy.x > 2 then
    guy.x = guy.x + motionx;
    guy.y = guy.y - motiony;
    end
         if guy.x == 2 then
    guy.x=3;
    end
if guy.x < 2 then
    guy.x=3;
    end
    if guy.x < _W - 2 then
    guy.x = guy.x + motionx;
    guy.y = guy.y - motiony;
    end
    if guy.x == _W - 2 then
    guy.x=_W-3;
    end
    if guy.x > _W - 2 then
    guy.x=_W-3;
    end

end
    end
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", moveguy)

-- When left arrow is touched, move character left
function left:touch()
    motionx = -speed;
end
left:addEventListener("touch",left)

-- When right arrow is touched, move character right
function right:touch()
    motionx = speed;
end
right:addEventListener("touch",right)
-- When up arrow is touched, move character up
function up:touch()
    motiony = jump;
end
up:addEventListener("touch",up)
```

just that line

```
local myText = display.newText(score,_W-20,_H-20, native.systemFont, 30 )
```

i tried everything i need you help

Comment: Thank you for providing your code, but I think you need to try to restate clearly what you question is or what issue(s) you are having.

Comment: texts isnt displaing i dont know why or what is the reason

Comment: It's best to clarify by editing your question directly.

Comment: can but this is the question

Comment: i posted the whole code only if you needed i also posted the text line

Comment: provide a screenshot, tell us what you have tried so far. we don't care how many days you have spent. we have to know what you did in those 2 days to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Not a corona expert but I have quite some experience in graphics/GUI programming.

To me it looks weird that you add the text befor you add the background. This would cause problems in all frameworks I have worked with so far.

Imagine you want to paint a car on a road. If you paint the car first you will paint the road over the car. You end up with a picture of a road...

Just a guess. Maybe corona is clever enough to put texts into a top layer automatically. But I find that hard to believe.

Comment: Yes, he needs to add the text after the other display objects.

Answer (score 0):

Your text is displayed behind the background, because created before. I recommand using groups so as to create a background, middle and front layer, and THEN create your display objects of the scene and add them in the group you want.